# Magento 2 : How to Add Date Validator on Custom Input Form Js File

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript, validation, date

I have created a custom input on the checkout page, I want to add date validator from js but I can't.

I already tried this custom js:

```
$( "#co-shipping-method-form" ).validate({
    rules: {
        myinputname: {
            required: true,
            date: true
        }
    }
});
```

and this one also.

```
jQuery('#co-shipping-method-form').formValidation({
    fields: {
        myinputname: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                message: 'The date of birth is required'
            },
            date: {
                format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
                message: 'The date of birth is not valid'
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Does anyone know what is the proper way to do this?